# Can I just pick the FOR loop in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop

High!

I'm new to PHP.

I was wondering- if I can choose FOR loop from all four and just use that?

It seems more readable, at least for me.

I understand that there are some speed differences, but in what I need to do- they probably don't matter that much.

Are there situations, where I can't use the for loop and must use other loops?

Thank You!

Comment: _can choose FOR loop from all four_ which four?

Comment: @vivek_23 `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `do-while`, I presume.

Comment: If you have array with __string keys__ - you can't use `for` loop to iterate over it.

Comment: So what about describing us what you need to do? Without this information we can only guess and that 's not good at all. So please read this: [How to ask good questions on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In one way or another, all the different loop constructs can be used interchangeably. But it might need some fiddling, to get the condition phrased correctly in each case, or additional data preparation upfront.

Comment: I wouldn’t fixate on just one specific type of loop construct, if that makes the code _less_ readable in certain situations. Sure, you _could_ loop over a database result with a `for` loop - but almost _everyone_ knows how to do that with a `while` instead, that’s what you will find in most examples, etc. Doing your own thing in a situation like this, just out of some sort of “principle”, would not make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is fine. It works and it's not particularly inefficient. But even (or especially) if you're still inexperienced, i'd advise getting used to the other loops as well. You'll need to use `while` over `for` if you can't determine how many times you need to loop, and a `foreach`, while a tiny bit more complex syntactically, can be much more readable when working with arrays of objects for an example.

There's nothing wrong with preferring the `for` loop, but try to experiment with other concepts if you're in the right mindspace.

There's also a ton more options to iterate over data, like `array_map` for an example.

Comment: Great answer!

I think I will stick mostly with for loop for the beginning, until i get the hang of it and then dig into other loops. If I need for loop to run until the end of the array, I can set the second condition to count() the array items on its own.